# React Native 0.57 Android app release crashes on startup

Tags: android, react-native

So we recently upgraded all the deps (rn frmo 0.55 to 0.57) and now it crashes in the middle of startup

the only log we get from logcat is

```
2019-01-08 14:22:10.523 25091-25115/? E/ReactNativeJS: TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

This error is located at:
    in n
    in Connect(n)
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in h
    in withCachedChildNavigation(h)
    in RCTView
    in AndroidDrawerLayout
    in DrawerLayoutAndroid
    in _
    in Unknown
    in h
    in P
    in n
    in Unknown
    in l
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in c
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance => do you use destructuring in your JS ? something like `const { a, b, ...rest} = someObj` ?

Comment: whereever that is, it looks like somewhere in react native code, not mine. and also when i build it on local computer, all is good

Comment: You have the same problem on a new project created with react-native init ? You should definitively create a test Project with this helper to compare your dependencies, it could be related to Babel